# Do Loop contained in a function defined within a custom package doesn’t work as expected but works fine when function is defined directly in a script

Tags: matrix, function-construction, evaluation, control-systems

Below is my code and I am having problems running the StdMPC function that I am trying to define. Running my code gives me the error that the matrix A and Xopt[[i]] are not of compatible shapes for matrix multiplication.

OptControlVector is a custom function I have defined in another package that gives me a list. In my code, I want to get the output from OptControlVector, take its first 'm' elements and store in a row of a matrix Uopt, calculate and assign the next row of Xopt (using the previous row of Xopt and same row no. of Uopt) and do this iteratively T number of times. So, I use the Do loop.

```
StdMPC[A_,B_,Ax_,Au_,Af_,bx_,bu_,bf_,Q_,Qf_,R_,initcond_,N_,T_]:= 

    Module[{
          Uopt=ConstantArray[0,{T,1}],
          Uopttemp,
          m=Dimensions[B][[2]],
          Xopt=ConstantArray[0,{T+1,1}]},
          Xopt[[1]]=initcond; 
          Do[
            Uopttemp=OptControlVector[A,B,Ax,Au,Af,bx,bu,bf,Q,Qf,R,Xopt[[i]],N];
            Uopt[[i]]=Uopttemp[[1;;m]];
            Xopt[[i+1]]=A.Xopt[[i]]+B.Uopt[[i]],
            {i,T}]
    ;Uopt]
```

This error made me suspicious that all the expressions in my Do loop are not being evaluated and that Xopt[[i+1]] was not being evaluated which resulted in Xopt[[2]] and so on being {0}. I then did this: In first case, I inserted Print[i] as the first expression in the Do loop and then in another case, put it as the second or third expression in the Do loop. The below code shows the first case I tried.

```
 StdMPC[A_,B_,Ax_,Au_,Af_,bx_,bu_,bf_,Q_,Qf_,R_,initcond_,N_,T_]:= 

    Module[{
          Uopt=ConstantArray[0,{T,1}],
          Uopttemp,
          m=Dimensions[B][[2]],
          Xopt=ConstantArray[0,{T+1,1}]},
          Xopt[[1]]=initcond; 
          Do[
            Print[i];
            Uopttemp=OptControlVector[A,B,Ax,Au,Af,bx,bu,bf,Q,Qf,R,Xopt[[i]],N];
            Uopt[[i]]=Uopttemp[[1;;m]];
            Xopt[[i+1]]=A.Xopt[[i]]+B.Uopt[[i]],
            {i,T}]
    ;Uopt]
```

The output for this printed i=1,2,3 for T=3, as expected. However, for the second case, all I got was i=2 printed three times for T=3. The code for the second case is

```
StdMPC[A_,B_,Ax_,Au_,Af_,bx_,bu_,bf_,Q_,Qf_,R_,initcond_,N_,T_]:= 

    Module[{
          Uopt=ConstantArray[0,{T,1}],
          Uopttemp,
          m=Dimensions[B][[2]],
          Xopt=ConstantArray[0,{T+1,1}]},
          Xopt[[1]]=initcond; 
          Do[
            Uopttemp=OptControlVector[A,B,Ax,Au,Af,bx,bu,bf,Q,Qf,R,Xopt[[i]],N];
            Print[i];
            Uopt[[i]]=Uopttemp[[1;;m]];
            Xopt[[i+1]]=A.Xopt[[i]]+B.Uopt[[i]],
            {i,T}]
    ;Uopt]
```

I have been trying to debug this for the past 3-4 hours now and I would be extremely grateful is someone could point out any mistakes here.

EDIT: Here is a picture showing the output of OptControlVector for certain values of the parameters. Kindly ignore the commented sections, they aren't relevant.
[image]

UPDATE: I was playing around and I surprisingly found that instead of writing StdMPC in a package and importing that package, if I directly define the function and run it in a script, it works without any error, perfectly! I haven't changed anything, just copy pasted the StdMPC definition from package to my script. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Please indent your code to make it legible, then provide a possible example of the value of OptControlVector for a specific set of parameters, and the values of those parameters. It’s much easier to debug code if we can actually run it, and currently we cannot because we don’t have complete code.

Comment: It’s a bit hard to tell, but it doesn’t look like your Do loop actually has an iterator. It should always be Do[..., iterator], but I don’t think I see one here.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry for the unindented code, I have edited to make it look cleaner now. I have also added an image which shows the output of OptControlVector for certain parameter values, which are also in the image. The package in which OptControlVector is, uses a couple of other packages (these are packages I have written). I can share the package scripts (maybe via Google Drive) if you would like to run my code.

Comment: @MassDefect I think the more cleaner view of my code after edit makes it visible that I have something like {i,T} where i is the iterator and T is max. value of the iterator.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just missed it, sorry.

Comment: @MarcoB and MassDefect I have found an interesting thing. Please look at the update section in my question.

Comment: @ModCon "Any ideas why this happens?" We could only guess. You still haven't given us complete, copy/pastable code we can play with. Please edit your question to remove all old material, since it has not been answered yet, and focus it on the new point. Make sure to include code **as text** and not as pictures. Make the effort of removing anything unnecessary yourself, but make sure that one can copy/paste your code from your question into a MMA session and execute it without errors or external dependencies (you need to create a so-called *minimal working example*, MWE).